# Portfolio choice to maximize expectation of first order statistic among binary random variables

Tags: optimization, order-statistics

$X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ are independently distributed binary random variables. A portfolio is a set of $m < n$ of these.

The value of a portfolio $\{X_{i_1},\dots, X_{i_m}\}$ is $\max(X_{i_1},\dots, X_{i_m})$ (i.e. the first order statistic of the variables in the portfolio).

Is there an efficient algorithm to select from the $n \choose m$ possibilities a  portfolio with the highest expected value (i.e. to maximize the expectation of the first order statistic)?

I've only been able to think of the brute force solution to this optimization problem. It doesn't seem that a greedy approach works. Most of what I've been able to find on first order statistics deals with continuous distributions. And all of the work on portfolio choice that I've found deals with maximizing the expected sum.

Comment: Assuming $E[X_i]=p_i$ the value of the portfolio is $0$ when all selected $X_i=0$, so you can evaluate the expected value and easily maximise it selecting the variables with greatest expected value

Comment: I had in mind that $E[X_i] = p_iv_i$ (with probability $p_i$ $X_i$ is realized to be $v_i$ and with probability $1-p_i$ it is $0$). If the value of the portfolio were $\sum_{k=1}^m X_{i_k}$, what you say makes perfect sense to me: picking the $m$ variables with highest expected values maximizes the expected value of the portfolio.
On the other hand, when the value of the portfolio is the first order statistic, it isn't obvious to me that the same solution is optimal. Am I missing something super trivial here?

Comment: Sorry, I always used "binary variable" in the sense of "bernoulli variable" (coin toss). So, let's say that $X_i=v_iB_i$ where $B_i$ is a bernoulli random variable with probability $p_i$, to evaluate the expectation of the max of all $X_i$ you can find an ordered index $o_i$ so that $v_{o_i}>v_{o_j}$ for $j>i$ and $E[\max(X_1,\cdots,X_n)]=v_{o_1}p_{o_1}+(1-p_{o_1})v_{o_2}p_{o_2}+\cdots+\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-p_{o_k})v_{o_n}p_{o_n}$. A greedy algorithm to select $m$ items could be to drop the item that gives the least drop in expectation. I tried a couple simulations and it seems to work.

Comment: No problem. And thanks for the reply!

Comment: I should have posted sooner, but something close to what you’re suggesting (might even be the same) is optimal: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1468-0262.2006.00705.x
They start with the variable with highest expected value. They then successively add variables that increase the expectation the most (the largest _marginal_ contribution).

Comment: I'm happy you found what you were looking for. Have a merry Christmas!

Answer (score 1):

This article addresses exactly the question I had posted about:
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1468-0262.2006.00705.x